# PreferenceScreenの閉じ方を教えてください

Tags: android, kotlin, xml, android-fragments

KotlinとPreference Libraryを用いてユーザー設定のあるアプリケーションを作ったのですが設定画面を閉じる方法がわかりません。
上にタイトルバーがそこのボタンを押すと戻る感じにしたいです
(見た目がダサいので設定画面以外ではタイトルバーは表示したくないです）

**見本**
[image: スクリーンショット]

***setting.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="OnOff"
        android:summaryOn="オン"
        android:summaryOff="オフ"
        android:title="OnOff" />

    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="OFF"
        android:entries="@array/reply_entries"
        android:entryValues="@array/reply_values"
        android:key="level"
        android:title="List preference"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

**Seeting.kt**

```
package com.example.myapp

import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat
import com.example.sugoidentaku.R

class Setting : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        // res/xml/preferences.xml ファイルに従って設定画面を構成
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.setting, rootKey)
    }
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
 supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.setting,Setting())
            .commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

`addToBackStack` でトランザクションを保存すればいいのではないでしょうか?

```
supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.setting,Setting())
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
```